# Gridgain: Write timed out (socket was concurrently closed)

Tags: gridgain

While trying to upload data to Gridgain using GridDataLoader, I'm getting

```
'Write timed out (socket was concurrently closed).'
```

I'm trying to load 10 million lines of data using a .csv file on a cluster having 13 nodes (16 core cpu).

The structure of my GridDataLoader is GridDataLoader where Key is a composite key. While using a primitive data type as the key there was no issue. But when I changed it to a composite key this error is coming.

Comment: Can you make sure that you have enough memory? Also, can you post the code for your composite key here? And lastly, what is your GridGain version (can you get the latest 6.5.6)?

Comment: i'm using the following as composite key, class Key {private long msisdn, private int kpiId}. The version is 6.5.5

Comment: The reason I asked you to paste your key class is because I wanted to see the implementation of the "equals" and "hashCode" methods. Did you implement those?

Comment: I did the default implementation that eclipse provide. 
 public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + (int) (MSISDN ^ (MSISDN >>> 32));
  result = prime * result + kpiID;
  return result;
 }


 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj)
   return true;
  if (obj == null)
   return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
   return false;
  Key other = (Key) obj;
  if (MSISDN != other.MSISDN)
   return false;
  if (kpiID != other.kpiID)
   return false;
  return true;
 }

Comment: OK, then the last thing is to check the memory consumption. Can you start VisualVM and check Heap utilization?

Comment: Size: 5,109,710,848 B
Used: 1,773,969,784 B
Max: 12,650,020,864 B

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because it takes up too large space on heap when it tries to parse your csv and create entries. As a result, if you don't configure your heap-size large enough, you are likely suffering from GC pauses since when GC kicks in, everything has to pause,  and that's why you got this time out error. I think it may help if you can break that large csv into smaller files and load them one by one.